# Create multiple columns from multiple return value of lambda function of resampled dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Referring to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421045/create-multiple-columns-from-multiple-return-value-of-lambda-function-in-python) I was trying to apply a function to a time series that returns multiple values. It is suggesting a workaround with pd.Series object.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def some_function(data):
    mu, std = norm.fit(data)
    a = mu * 3
    b = std * 5
    return a, b


rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
r = ts.resample('2h')
r[['a', 'b']] = r.agg(lambda x: pd.Series(some_function(x)))
```

However, I want to apply this to resampled data while getting the following error. I am know what is the issue, but cannot figure out how to achieve my goal.

```
ValueError: cannot set items on DatetimeIndexResampler
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
                       a   b
2011-01-01 00:00:00    mu1 std1
2011-01-01 02:00:00    mu2 std2
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
def some_function(data):
    mu, std = norm.fit(data)
    a = mu * 3
    b = std * 5
    return a, b
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
ts.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('2H')).apply(some_function).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'a',1:'b'})

Out[964]: 
                            a         b
2011-01-01 00:00:00  2.421663  5.230464
2011-01-01 02:00:00 -0.757646  0.966690
2011-01-01 04:00:00  1.642813  1.282784
```

Comment: Sorry, the function was a bad example. I have edited my post.

Comment: Cheers! How can one define "pd.TimeGrouper('')" such that it subsets groups the months over all year?

Comment: For more information https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html

Comment: Ok, but I cannot find such an example :-(

Comment: @Peterhack Can you show me the data and the expected output ? I think I can help
 you out

Comment: You can consider the same Data, but what I am expecting ist just 12 value pairs, so that I have an distribution for everyone month across all years.

Comment: @Peterhack chaneg to `pd.TimeGrouper('6H')` will give back you 12 rows output

Comment: Sorry, in that case my daterange example is not applicable anymore. Consider this: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=365*4, freq='D'). Now, we have four years and I am looking for 12 value pairs such that I have a distribution for every month across years.

Comment: @Peterhack If this would not sloved the problem , `ts.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('4M')).apply(some_function).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'a',1:'b'})`
maybe you can open a new question show your expected output as well , since this is uncorrelated with your original one.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers, you got me on the right way as this seems to work. But maybe there is an even better solution?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm


def some_function(data):
    mu, std = norm.fit(data)
    a = mu * 3
    b = std * 5
    return a, b


rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
s = ts.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('2H')).apply(some_function)
df = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), columns=['a', 'b'], index=s.index)
```