# How to locate multiple returned values from a function into multiple columns of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function to calculate max frequency item and its rate, I want to set these values in 
NaN_values of two different columns in a dataframe:
(note: each column has other values (non_NaN values), I want to fillna)

```
  Id    numbers     max_frq    rate
   1   1,1,1,2,3     NaN       NaN
   2   1,6,6,6       NaN       NaN
   3   7,7           NaN       NaN
```

expected:

```
  id    numbers     max_frq    rate
   1   1,1,1,2,3      1       0.6
   2   1,6,6,6        6       0.75
   3   7,7            7       1.0
```

this my code which fills all NaN values in columns by repeated values (first value of max_no, first value of rate).
**how to fill each Id row by its associated values**?

```
def max_rate(Id) # Id is a list 
    num = pd.Series(numbers).value_counts()
    max_no = num.max()
    sum_no = num.sum()
    rate = max_no / sum_no
    return max_no, rate_no

for Id in (df["Id"].unique()):
    max_no, rate_no = max_rate(Id)
    df.max_frq = df.max_frq.fillna(max_no)
    df.rate = df.rate.fillna(rate_no)
```

I also checked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421045/create-multiple-columns-from-multiple-return-value-of-lambda-function-in-python) but I couldn't understand how to use **lambda** and **series** and where to put (**fillna**) condition, I coded this

```
for Id in (df["Id"].unique()):
    g = lambda x: pd.Series(max_rate(x))
    df[['max_frq', 'rate']] = df.apply(g, axis=1)
```

and get error:
('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()', 'occurred at index 50')

Comment: Why's the rate for the last column 0.5? Shouldn't that be 1?

Comment: Probably, you shouldn't be storing lists of numbers in a pandas dataframe in the first place, four all intents and purposes, this is inefficient. Use multi level indices or two columns for `Id` and `row in Id`.

Comment: @thushv89 you are right, it is (1.0), sorry for confusion.

Comment: @MaxNoe the list is the output of previous operation, numbers for illustration, could you explain your idea by example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you need for each row:

- Find the most common value in the list of numbers
- Find what part of all occurrences is the most common one
- Store result in two new columns

Please see the code below.

```
from collections import Counter


def max_rate(values):
    most_common, num_most_common = Counter(values).most_common(1)[0]
    return most_common, num_most_common / len(values)

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [[1, 1, 1, 2, 3], 
                               [1, 6, 6, 6], 
                               [7, 7]]})

df[['most_common', 'rate']] = pd.DataFrame(df['numbers'].apply(max_rate).tolist())
print(df)
```

Result:

```
           numbers  most_common  rate
0  [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]            1  0.60
1     [1, 6, 6, 6]            6  0.75
2           [7, 7]            7  1.00
```

If you don't want to use *Counter* you can implement max_rate function as below

```
def max_rate(values):
    most_common_value = max(values, key=values.count)
    return most_common_value, values.count(most_common_value) / len(values)
```

**Edit:**
If you want to explicitly create data frame with columns which already contain NaN values you can do something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [[1, 1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7]]})
df['most_common'] = np.nan
df['rate'] = np.nan

result = df['numbers'].apply(max_rate)
for i, (most_common, rate) in zip(df.index, result):
    df.at[i, 'most_common'] = most_common
    df.at[i, 'rate'] = rate
```

In that solution, you can iterate through data fame and update it row by row with received results. However, I like more the previous way where you just create new columns from the obtained result.

**Edit2:**

If you necessarily want to use *fillna* you can try as below, however, in my opinion, it is still going around the first solution.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [[1, 1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7]]})
df['most_common'] = np.nan
df['rate'] = np.nan

result = df['numbers'].apply(max_rate)

df = df.fillna({'most_common': pd.Series([elem[0] for elem in result]),
                'rate': pd.Series([elem[1] for elem in result])})
```

Comment: my problem is how to locate the returned values of function in NaN values in df, if i am right, your way seem to create new column in df, where the condition of fill NaN?